# Cancelling Windows Forms Events

Tags: winforms, events

I have a windows form. It has a `ComboBox` and a `DataGrid`

I have a `Leave` event on my `ComboBox` and I have a `DoubleClick` event on my `DataGrid` row

The idea is that on leaving the `ComboBox`, if the value of the `ComboBox` changed then use the new value to reload the `DataGrid`.

Let's say the `ComboBox` is displaying a value of `1` and for that value there are 5 records displayed in the `DataGrid`.
Now the user enters `2` in the `ComboBox` and tabs away. In my `Leave` event I see that the value has changed and I reload the `DataGrid` with all the records for that value.

But if the user enters `2` and double clicks on existing records for the value `1`, than the
leave event reloads the `DataGrid` and than the `DoubleClick` event FIRES.

How do I find a list of pending events and cancel each and every one of them, if the `DataGrid` has been reloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an event order problem, the DataGridView.Enter event fires too soon.  This can be cleanly solved by delaying event actions with the Control.BeginInvoke() method.  Its delegate target fires as soon as your program re-enters the message loop.  In other words, after all pending events have fired.  Make it look similar to this:

```
private bool selectionDirty;

private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  selectionDirty = true;
}

private void dataGridView1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => selectionDirty = false));
}

private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
  if (selectionDirty) return;
  // etc...
}
```

Comment: i'll give this a try Monday morning

Comment: I dont think this will work. because upon entering the datagrid, there is no guarantee that it was reloaded.

Comment: I need Jon Skeet or Ayende here to help me out

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `Leave` Event, try [`SelectedIndexChanged` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx), that would be fired before the `DataGrid`s `DoubleClick` event. The downside is if the user is scrolling the `ComboBox` with the keyboard, then it will fire 5 times if the user scrolls 5 steps down in the `ComboBox`.

Another solution would be to store a local variable `lComboEntered=true` when entering the `ComboBox` and set the value to `false` when the `Leave` event fires. And in the `DataGrid` `DoubleClick` event check if the `lComboEntered=false` before doing anything.

Comment: In my leave event routine, if the combobox value has changed than i reload the datagrid AND set a CancelDoubleClick Flag to TRUE. Inside my datagrid doubleclick routine, I check this flag and cancel the event if it is true. This works fine if I change value in my combobox and double click a row without doing anything else. But if i enter a value in the combobox and simply tab away than i have to double click the datagrid TWICE. where else Could i reset that flag to FALSE.